# html5 audio of video play after pause

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, html5-video, html5-audio

I am working with **bootstrap** and **html5 video player**.
My video is opening in bootstrap modal.

I want to stop video and audio when user close the overlay. Below is my code for the same.

```
$(".myModal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {

    var _this = this,
        $videoObj = $(_this).find("video").get(0),
        $videoObjSource = $($videoObj).find("source")[0];


    if ($(_this).find("video").length > 0) {

        console.log('Pausing video...');
        $videoObj.pause();
        //$videoObjSource.removeAttribute("src");

    }
});
```

Now, its closing and pausing the video but audio of video is still being playing. I want to close or pause the video as well. This is the issue.

Please help.

Regards 
Anand Deep Singh

Comment: What is happening if you remove `src` attribute?

Comment: It works for me right away -> **http://jsfiddle.net/75oocwuc/** `var video = document.getElementById("video"); video.pause();` would be far more easy than the cryptic code above, though :)